# Does wit.ai prioritize what it ask me to validate? (e.g low confidence score results)

Tags: wit.ai

I am training `wit.ai` understanding, I use `python` script to make api call and feed `wit.ai` with sentences stored in a local file.
There is more data (~thousands) than I can manually validate (hundreds).

Does `wit.ai` prioritize what it ask me to validate? e.g. those that has low confidence score or "no match"

From my experience, I did not see this kind of optimization for `wit.ai`. If this is true, I need to do some optimization in my training process, and avoid flooding `wit.ai` with similar data that reach high confidence score quickly.